# Solve this progression riddle

Tags: riddle

Solve the Puzzle:

[image]

Hint:

> Answer is not 98!

Comment: Why have you posted this with answer? everyone's answer will be 98 no one will say intended answer unless you provide any hint

Comment: Considering that this puzzle is all over the internet in different shapes or forms, I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Well... my guess is

> 99

Because:

> `3*2  + 1 = 7`
>  `5*4  + 3 = 23`
>  `7*6  + 5 = 47`
>  `9*8  + 7 = 79`
>  `10*9 + 9 = 99`

Answer (score 1):

I think answer is

> 99

**Logic :**

> b*b + a + (previous b)
>
> 2*2 + 3 = 7
>
> 4*4 + 5 + 2 =23
>
> 6*6 +7 + 4 =47
>
> 8*8 + 9 + 6 =79
>
> 9*9 + 10 + 8 = **99**

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer is

> 98

Because

> The equation for each line is $a * b + (b-1)$

This kind of puzzle doesn't rely on a logic between each line. They all need to correspond to the same logic, no matter the order of the equations.

Comment: If I can explain for any downvoter: I didn't read the bottom part, so yes I had the same answer but I also gave an explanation.

Comment: Well, this might be a correct answer as the puzzle stated that the answer is not $98!$ a.k.a $9426890448883247745626185743057242473809693764078951663494238777294707070023223798882976159207729119823605850588608460429412647567360000000000000000000000$, :p

Comment: @athin you just broke the CSS of the website, good job! Well this puzzle is not very clear, OP never stated that the answer wasn't "98!"